# Use Chef Cookbook Methods in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

is there a way to use Chef methods like "yum_package" in a ruby script, executed by standard ruby environment and not in a chef cookbook?

I try to install and remove yum packages in a ruby script and i was thinking about using the methods chef is offering in cookbooks. Chef is already installed on the system.

What i tried is:

```
require "/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef.rb"
Chef::Resource::YumPackage.property("vim","7.4.160")
Chef::Resource::YumPackage.action(:install)
```

I am a beginner in ruby and not sure if i am on the right way.
Have somebody tried to use chef Methods in Ruby before? I hope you could help me out with that Problem.

Thanks Til

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can do directly, using the Chef DSL requires a lot of stuff to be set up in the background. If you are looking to write a simple script using the Chef recipe DSL, check out the `chef-apply` command.